# Prolog Recursive Build List of [--I, ++J], while J>0

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm trying to put together a Prolog program that will take in a number and an output list, and essentially make a list of the form [I, J], where I+J = N. Here's the code I have, with the output I'm getting:

```
loop(I, J, [[X,Y]|Lout]):-
  I > 0,
  I1 is I-1,
  J1 is J+1,
  X is I1,
  Y is J1,
  loop(I1, J1, Lout).
loop(I, J, [[I,J]]).

listFromLoop(N, W):-
  loop(N,0,W).
```

Output:

```
?- listFromLoop(4,W).
W = [[3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3], [0, 4], [0, 4]] ;
W = [[3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3]] ;
W = [[3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]] ;
W = [[3, 1], [3, 1]] ;
W = [[4, 0]].
```

I'm getting two extra elements at the end ([0,4], [0,4]) that I don't need, as well as having to step through it, rather than it all being displayed as a single list.

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

```
?- listFromLoop(4,W).
W = [[3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3]].
```

I'm close, but I think my main problem is that I'm trying to code it like I would a C++ or Java while-loop. However, that doesn't seem to be the proper way to go about it in Prolog.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I figured it out! After a little bit more reading, it seemed I was missing my base case for the recursive version. Here is what I ended up with that fixed it. Although, I'm not certain this is necessarily the correct/most efficient way to do this in Prolog.

```
loop(1,_,[]):- !.
loop(I, J, [[X,Y]|Lout]):-
  I > 0,
  I1 is I-1,
  J1 is J+1,
  X is I1,
  Y is J1,
loop(I1, J1, Lout).

listFromLoop(N, W):-
  loop(N,0,W).
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "make a list of the form [I, J], where I+J = N"?

Comment: I'll do my best. For example, for N=4 an element of the list would be [3,1], which is can be seen as 3+1. It's meant to represent the decompositions for CYK Parse Table formation. The list should contain all such combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but I would do this kind of thing to clean it up a bit:

```
build(1, _, []).
build(I, J, [[X, Y]|Zs]) :-
    I > 1,
    X is I - 1,
    Y is J + 1,
    build(X, Y, Zs).

build(N, W) :- build(N, 0, W).
```

You're not really using a loop - it's recursion that builds the list. So just call it `build`. It's also perfectly fine to define predicates with the same name but a different number of parameters.

I've also named `Lout` as `Zs` as this helps indicate that it's a list - prolog doesn't usually care about inputs or outputs anyway. You could run the query `?- build(6, [[5, 1], [4, 2], [3, 3], [2, 4], [1, 5]]).` and you'll get success even though you've sent the output list in as an input parameter.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I wasn't sure if the recursion was working properly, so I just left it named as loop. I appreciate the extra explanation and cleaned up code.

Comment: @WhiskeyJack - No worries. And I also set `I > 1` to make the first two `build/2` predicates to be mutually exclusive cases - then there's no need for the cut (`!`).

Answer (score 0):

a more idiomatic way:

```
listFromLoop(U,W) :- U_ is U-1,
    findall([I,J],(between(1,U_,J),I is U_-J+1),W).
```